# http://example.com, http://www.example.com and https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

Our second question on Stack Overflow! Our aim is to permanently redirect all requests for our site to `https://www.example.com`. We currently have the below code in place to redirect `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, but, after spending quite some time on Stack Overflow looking for a solution, we have not yet found a way to also redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. Would much appreciate your help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to handle this in one single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and force https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

- Keep this rule as your very first rule.
- Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test it.
- Change `302` to `301` after you've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @anubhava's elegant solution for Apache, we recently found a way to do the same on Nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```